# Is customizing a character’s in roblox imitating Allah’s creation

Tags: halal-haram, sin, game, doubts

I want to play a game but before I do I would like to know if this is permissible please answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aslamualaikum,
A word of advice for my fellow brother is I would leave the game especially if your over the age of puberty.

I used to to be a novice developer[for quite some time too] on there and while animating I realized that it mimics the creation and even more so if you want to change the default roblox character. A roblox character can be described as a humanoid with human like appearances (a face) a torso, two arms, and two legs. It can jump, walk, and dance too.

I know this might sound like a stretch and I am no position to pull a fatwa.

Look at like these following hadiths:

**Playing with dolls before puberty (which is allowed) :**

> I used to play with the dolls in the presence of the Prophet, and my
> girl friends also used to play with me. When Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
> used to enter (my dwelling place) they used to hide themselves, but
> the Prophet would call them to join and play with me. (The playing
> with the dolls and similar images is forbidden, but it was allowed for
> `Aisha at that time, as she was a little girl, not yet reached the age
> of puberty.) (Fath-ul-Bari page 143, Vol.13)

**Severe punishment in which those who mimic the creation of Allah:**

> Aishah (May Allah be pleased with her) said: The Messenger of Allah
> (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) visited me after returning from a
> journey, and I had a shelf with a thin cloth curtain hanging over it
> and on which there were portraits. When he saw it, the colour of his
> face changed (because of anger) and he said, "O Aishah! the most
> grievous torment from Allah on the Day of Resurrection will be for
> those who imitate (Allah) in the act of His creation.'' `Aishah said:
> We tore it into pieces and made a cushion or two cushions out of that.
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

**Images and Dogs prevent Angels (which are a form of mercy for the believers):**

> A'isha reported that Gabriel (peace be upon him) made a promise with
> Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) to come at a definite hour;
> that hour came but he did not visit him. And there was in his hand (in
> the hand of Allah's Apostle) a staff. He threw it from his hand and
> said: Never has Allah or His messengers (angels) ever broken their
> promise. Then he cast a glance (and by chance) found a puppy under his
> cot and said: 'A'isha, when did this dog enter here? She said: By
> Allah, I don't know. He then commanded and it was turned out. Then
> Gabriel came and Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) said to
> him: You promised me and I waited for you, but you did not come,
> whereupon he said: It was the dog in your house which prevented me (to
> come), for we (angels) do not enter a house in which there is a dog or
> a picture. Muslim :: Book 24 : Hadith 5246

However, the Prophet did allow the drawing of inanimate objects such as trees and rocks -- anything which does not possess a soul.

> Ibn Abbas (May Allah be pleased with them) said: I heard the Messenger
> of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) saying, "Every painter will
> go to Hell, and for every portrait he has made, there will be
> appointed one who will chastise him in the Hell.'' Ibn `Abbas said: If
> you have to do it, draw pictures of trees and other inanimate things.
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

*Today you have many 3D models in the gaming world and in the realm of media, do you know how much fitnah this causes (the perversion and the seeds of shirk being planted in the hearts of people) ? When you play such games you are contributing to the profits of the developers and the industry as a whole, you increase the player count/visits and indirectly encourage others to continue this type of vice.*

**This might sound harsh but focus on constructive sunnahs like sports and other activities that are useful:**

> That the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Indeed, Allah will surely admit
> three into Paradise by a single arrow. Its maker who seeks good by his
> making it, the one who shoots it, and the one who holds arrows for
> him." And he said: "Practice archery and practice riding, and the you
> should practice archery is more beloved to me than that you should
> ride. All idle pastimes that the Muslim man engages in are falsehood,
> except for his shooting of his bow, his training of his horse, and his
> playing with his wife, for they are from truth." Grade:    Sahih
> (Darussalam)

Other sunnah sports include **racing, wrestling, strength training**. I guess you could play other things like soccer/basketball/football since they all work on your body I guess. *If you are not interested in these areas you can increase your academic backbone or other hobbies which will help you be a better person and help others.*

*Even if part of Roblox is halal and some other things are doubtful and haram (like roleplaying and dating which does occur surprisingly with kids nowadays). It's better to leave the smoke and keep clean, perhaps Allah might reward and replace for you something much better in this world and hereafter for you.*

> On the authority Abi Ab’dillahi al-Nu’man ibn Basheer (ra) who said: I
> heard the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) say: “That which is
> lawful is clear and that which is unlawful is clear and between the
> two of them are doubtful [or ambiguous] matters about which not many
> people are knowledgeable. Thus, he who avoids these doubtful matters
> certainly clears himself in regard to his religion and his honor. But
> he who falls into the doubtful matters falls into that which is
> unlawful like the shepherd who pastures around a sanctuary, all but
> grazing therein. Verily every king has a sanctuary and Allah’s
> sanctuary is His prohibition. In the body there is a morsel of flesh
> which, if it be sound, all the body is sound and which, if it be
> diseased, all the body is diseased. This part of the body is the
> heart”.  [Related by al-Bukhari and Muslim]

**Remember what Ibrahim said to his people?
إِذْ قَالَ لِأَبِيهِ وَقَوْمِهِۦ مَا هَـٰذِهِ ٱلتَّمَاثِيلُ ٱلَّتِىٓ أَنتُمْ لَهَا عَـٰكِفُونَ
When he said to his father and his people, "What are these statues to which you are devoted?"[21:52]**

There adults were devoted to idols and lost purpose, it all started with people first constructing images for harmless reasons like remembering the pious people. Today the gaming world is becoming more and more toxic, It's as if decency is being taken away from people (we seek refuge in Allah from that). It could be that the gaming community is heading towards something darker, think about it.

I only posted this comment out of care for you brother so I wish for you to take heed, it's very nice to see a person concerned what pleases Allah.

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Thank you brother I was gonna go back to play the game but I realized this could be imitating of Allah and I will play other games thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Technology though it appears strange an foreign is a natural part of our evolution.

Sometimes evolving is dirty and painful and we are evolving at an exponential rate. How we proceed will determine how we evolve. So proceed with caution and always seek truth and goodness. Now for the good part.. God always wins in the end.. So hold fast to the rope that is Allah.

One of the 99 names of Allah is Truth. Math is Truth and is therefore existent upon its own volition and falls under the authority of the spirit of Allah. Technology is what the ancients would have likely called "magic". In my personal opinion technology is sacred so again, proceed with caution. Don't let yourself be consumed by negative energy. Let  the fruit of your deeds be a sign of the tree that bore them.

Illusions and trickery is false magic used for deception but science, medicine and technology can be used for good. The answer is simple, are you hurting anyone? are you having fun? It comes down to our intentions. It's good to have fun and to enjoy yourself but don't let your time become wasteful.

when all else fails pray and God will surely guide you. peace and blessings be upon you.

Now to answer your question specifically. No! Roblox does not fall under imitation or manipualtion of creation it is part of creation. An example of imitating creation is to act like an animal or to manipulate your body in a way that is meant to impress the creation or to change your appearance by deforming your body. Biotech for example could fall under this type of sin. Used for medicine it's a good thing, used to enhance or distort the creation is a bad thing.

- A

Truth:
https://myislam.org/99-names-of-allah/al-haqq/

"Allah is Al-Haqq, the only reality, The One who is the truth. Since he is the only one and true God, he has every right to be worshipped. His essence is unavoidable"

Intentions of the heart:
https://yaqeeninstitute.org/amp/justin-parrott/the-guiding-principles-of-faith-sincerity-honesty-and-good-will-in-islam